# Is digital signing Form I-864 is acceptable?

Tags: financial

I am filling form I-864 to sponsor a family member.
I should submit the form online, and the form is pdf file which can get filled using a pdf editor.

My question is about a the signature needed on bottom of this form. Is it acceptable by NVC to put a digital signature on the pdf at designed box or not, I have to print the filled form and sign in by black ink and the scan the form into a new pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of December 2016](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/ink-signature-no-longer-required-on-affidavits-of-support.html), NVC no longer requires "wet ink" signatures on I-864 submitted to it. You can submit photocopies of the signed form, but they do not accept "digital signatures".

Comment: Since I have to upload a digital copy of completed form, should I do print, sign, scan, upload sequence?

Comment: @Polymorphic: I think so